# API design - restricting access

Tags: java, api, api-design

I have an API that I am designing, but I'm wondering about what would be appropriate for the sake of flexibility in restricting who can invoke a method.

Put simply, my API is a facade for another API, and tries to simplify a lot of the usage. There are methods for deserialization which the API I am building off of calls itself, but I'm wondering if I should restrict it so that the API is the *only* thing that can call it:

```
public static SLocation deserialize(Map<String, Object> config) {
    Validate.isTrue(Reflections.accessedFromAPI(), "Can only be called by <API>!"); //Reads the stack
    return new SLocation(config);
}
```

vs.

```
public static SLocation deserialize(Map<String, Object> config) {
    return new SLocation(config);
}
```

Typically, the users of my own API should not be aware of the internal implementations of these serializable classes, nor how they are written to a file. So in my opinion, it would make sense to restrict it so that only the "upstream" API can call them. However, would that be too restrictive in the spirit of making classes as flexible to use as possible?

Comment: There are pros and cons regarding such a restriction, however, a Reflection based caller-check is *dead slow* and not a real option…

Comment: @Holger I should mention (as the method didn't have any real good placement for a different utility class) that the `accessedFromAPI` method doesn't use reflection, but reads the `StackTraceElement`s.

Comment: generating a stack trace *is* an expensive operation and it’s considered to be a reflective operation, regardless of whether it is inside the `java.lang.reflect` package or not.

Comment: @Holger As of now, that's been my understanding as well. I've only used checks like that more for one-off methods (such as initializing hooks).